# Python django как создать одну форму на две модели и сохранить полученные данные в бд?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm, django-model

Есть две **связанные** модели в django.
Как создать одну форму на две модели и сохранить полученные данные в бд?

```
class QrCodes(models.Model):
q_url = models.ForeignKey('QrCodesUrls', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
img = models.ImageField(upload_to=f'qrcode', verbose_name='Img')

class QrCodesUrls(models.Model):
url = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Url', unique=True)

class QrCodesUrlsForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = QrCodesUrls

class QrCodesForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = QrCodesdef qrcodes(request):

def qrcodes(request):
form, form_u = QrCodesForm(request.POST, request.FILES), QrCodesUrlsForm(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid() and form_u.is_valid():
            form_u.save()
            form.save()
```

спасибо.

Comment: нужны примеры желаемого результата

Comment: Добавил код, не понятно как сохранить в бд